# Need help solving a math problem involving limits and the continuity of a function.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

I don't know if my start is correct and how should I go about solving this.

Q: Check the continuity of the function defined with:

$$f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{x+x^2e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}}}$$

I used the L'Hôpital's rule and solved the limit to get $$f(x)=x^2$$
Now... I don't know how to prove that this function is continuous even though I know it is.

My main question is if I was correct in the first step... that is, if solving the limit was the right thing to do... I guess it was since the function is in terms of x not n. If this question was already answered please, if its not a hassle, link me to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x + x^{2}e^{nx}}{ 1 + e^{nx}}$. Note that the limit changes as the value of $x$ varies. In fact, one can verify that:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x^{2} &  x > 0 \\  0 & x = 0 \\ x & x < 0 \end{cases},
$$
which is indeed a continuous function.